# DL Expressivity not available in Protégé Ontology Metrics View

Tags: semantic-web, protege

I installed Protégé 5.5 and I am interested in the DL expressivity of my ontology.

In the [documentation](http://protegeproject.github.io/protege/views/ontology-metrics/), it is written that this information should be found in the Ontology Metrics view. However, my view does not contain this particular information.

Do I need to install some additional plugin?

Comment: reported under https://github.com/protegeproject/protege/issues/896

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you cannot find the view, or that the view shows no information?

If it's the former, in Protege, navigate to Window > Views > Ontology views > Ontology metrics.

If it's the latter, you shouldn't need any additional plugin(s).

If the problem persists you'll need to post the file or some trivial example otherwise there is nothing to test.

Comment: I do find the view. And the view does contain metrics such as "Axiom", "Logical Axiom Count", "Declaration Axiom Count" and so on. However, the "DL expressivity" statistic is missing. It is not grayed out like some other statistics, it is simply not there.

Comment: Workaround: I installed Protégé 5.1. Surprisingly, I have the DL expressivity in that release.

Comment: You may want to ping the protege list.  If it's a bug they should know :)